# List Type is wrong, not sure which list type i need

Tags: c#, linq, function, types, casting

just a simple class, that im unsure of what list type i need to return, string doesnt work and neither does blank, should be simple for someone who knows.

Thanks for any help

```
public static List<> lstVMStats()
        {
            ITAPP.Models.DBEntities db = new ITAPP.Models.DBEntities();

            var varESxis = from d in db.tblVirtualServers 
                           group d by d.ESXiID into g 
                           orderby g.Count() descending, g.Key 
                           select new {
                            ESXi = g.Key,
                            Count = g.Count() 
                           };
            return varESxis.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: You haven't "filled in" your List: `public static List<> lstVMStats()` ...you'll have to give the list a type to expect.

Comment: You can create a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return `List<object>` from your method if your list contains anonymous objects. However it won't be terribly useful because other methods calling it can't access to the properties defined in an anonymous type. You should create a custom type for your results.

```
class VirtualServerInfo
{
    public string ESXi { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public static List<VirtualServerInfo> lstVMStats()
{
    ITAPP.Models.DBEntities db = new ITAPP.Models.DBEntities();

    var varESxis = from d in db.tblVirtualServers 
                   group d by d.ESXiID into g 
                   orderby g.Count() descending, g.Key 
                   select new VirtualServerInfo{
                    ESXi = g.Key,
                    Count = g.Count() 
                   };
    return varESxis.ToList();
}
```

Comment: when i use object, i get cannot covert anonynous type to object when i try return the list

Comment: i think this will work for me, however how do i iterate through the result in razor?     @foreach (var Item in ViewBag.VMStats)
    {
        Item["ESXi"];
        Item["Count"];
    }

Comment: @AlexW That also works but you lose the safety of strong typing.

Comment: using item["ESXi"] gives me error "only increment call assgin etc can be assigned" what do i need to put?

Comment: @AlexW I suppose you are trying to display it in a Razor view. You can do something like this `@foreach (var Item in ViewBag.VMStats) { <span>  @Item["ESXi"] </span> }`

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ITAPP.Helpers.helpers.VirtualServerInfo'

Comment: Use the property names - they aren't indexes or an indexed property. e.g. `<span>@Item.EXSi</span>`. Only arrays or indexed properties can be indexed - you have created a .NET type so literally just use the properties on each object with standard member access syntax

Comment: @AlexW Sorry I didn't get you the first time. You should just write `<span>@Item.EXSi</span>` like Charleh suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a Dictionary instead:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> lstVMStats()
{
    ITAPP.Models.DBEntities db = new ITAPP.Models.DBEntities();

    var varESxis = from d in db.tblVirtualServers 
                   group d by d.ESXiID into g 
                   orderby g.Count() descending, g.Key 
                   select new {
                     ESXi = g.Key,
                     Count = g.Count() 
                   };
    return varESxis.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, y=>y.Value);
}
```

Comment: If it's worth doing the `orderby` then it had better be an [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx).